# Customise groupBy

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this string in input:

```
1 2 lucky 4 buzz fizz
```

and I am trying to achieve the following output

```
 fizz: 1 buzz: 1 fizzbuzz: 0 lucky: 1 integer: 3
```

using the following code:

```
Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream(input).collect(groupingBy((val -> val.equals("fizz") ? "fizz"
            : val.equals("buzz") ? "buzz"
            : val.equals("lucky") ? "lucky"
            : "integers"),Collectors.counting())).toString();
}
```

I have read this nice tutorial https://blog.indrek.io/articles/creating-a-collector-in-java-8/ but it seems too complicated to achieve something that simple. Can you please show me how to achieve this using java8 streams?

**QUESTION HAS BEEN UPDATED BY FIXING THE BROKEN CODE**

Comment: Shouldn't the `lucky` count be 1?  Is the count of a missing item e.g. `fizzbuzz` required?

Comment: Yes, I have corrected it. Yes, the count of missing items should be there as well.

Comment: Just a typo, `Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream(input)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(val -> val.equals("fizz") ? "fizz" : val.equals("buzz") ? "buzz"
                : val.equals("lucky") ? "lucky"
                : "integers", Collectors.counting())).toString()` , see the brackets for `groupingBy`.

Comment: So what if word `foo` is present? Does it get counted or ignored?

Comment: never be present.

Comment: *FYI:* You can't make `groupingBy` invent a group for a missing value.

Comment: Nice, thanks @Andreas. Is there any way to change from = to :?

Comment: Thanks @Naman, got this now {lucky=1, buzz=1, integers=3}. How do I replace = to :?

Comment: By not using the default `toString` implementation of a `Map`.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it? @Naman

Comment: Bracket after ´"integers"` is too much and add one bracket after `counting'.

Comment: @user3727540 you can iterate over each entry and print them as you will, `Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream(input)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(val -> val.equals("fizz") ? "fizz" : val.equals("buzz") ? "buzz"
                        : val.equals("lucky") ? "lucky"
                        : "integers", Collectors.counting())).forEach((k, v) -> System.out.print(k + ": " + v + "  " ));`

Comment: @Naman I do not need to print it, but return the resulting string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can simply the value-mapping logic. Since you [claim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55245712/customise-groupby#comment97224674_55245712) that words other than the 4 words listed in the desired output cannot happen, you just need to map any numeric value to the word "integer":

```
groupingBy(s -> Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0)) ? "integer" : s, ...)
```

Second, you need to get missing words counted, but `grouping()` cannot invent groups for missing words.

Easiest would be to add missing groups after the fact:

```
List.of("fizz", "buzz", "fizzbuzz", "lucky", "integer")
    .forEach(s -> map.putIfAbsent(s, 0L));
```

Lastly, you want result as space-separated using `:` between key and value, so you cannot (well, should not) use `Map.toString()` method.

```
String input = "1 2 lucky 4 buzz fizz";
Map<String, Long> map = Pattern.compile(" ").splitAsStream(input)
        .collect(groupingBy(s -> (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0)) ? "integer" : s), counting()));
List.of("fizz", "buzz", "fizzbuzz", "lucky", "integer")
    .forEach(s -> map.putIfAbsent(s, 0L));
String output = map.entrySet().stream()
                   .map(e -> e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue())
                   .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(output);
```

*Output*

```
lucky: 1 integer: 3 fizz: 1 fizzbuzz: 0 buzz: 1
```

Comment: With Java-9 and above, `Collectors.filtering` possibly could help getting rid of the `putIfAbsent` operation.

Comment: @Naman `Collectors.filtering` is like `Streams.filter`, in that they are used to *exclude / remove* values, not add *missing* values, which is what is needed here.

Comment: But why not `String output = Stream.of("fizz", "buzz", "fizzbuzz", "lucky", "integer") .map(s -> s+": "+map.getOrDefault(s, 0)) .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));` instead of changing the map (mind that `groupingBy` does not guarantee to return a mutable map)? Then, even the output order matches the OP’s example.

Comment: And instead of `Character.isDigit(s.charAt(0))` you may use `s.matches("[0-9]+")`.